# broadcom 4313gn wifi adapter can't connect wifi 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I  have a HP sleekbook envy with a broadcom 4313gn wifi adapter, and i can't get the wireless adapter to work. I can see wireless connections that are available, but when i try to connect and put in the WEP key it tries to connect for around 1 minute and then asks me for the WEP key again, over and over again.

I have only gotten a wired connection to work with Ubuntu, but I know my wifi adapter is fine because i'm dual booting windows 7 with Ubuntu 12.04, and although the wifi reception isn't great i know it isn't a hardware problem (since it works with windows 7)

I have read several questions similar to this one (i tried to figure this out on my own first), but none of them had a clear solution. I thought i would just need to download a driver...

Also, i wouldn't be against upgrading my wifi adapter to one that Ubuntu supports, this one doesn't seem very good. But i'd rather get this one working if possible.

edit:
 these are the results from the terminal commands:

`lspci -nn | grep 0280`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

`lsmod | grep -e wl -e brcmsmac`:

```
wl                   3074895  0 
cfg80211              205774  1 wl
lib80211               14381  2 lib80211_crypt_tkip,wl
```

edit 2:
I'm not sure if i ran it correctly...

ryan@ubuntu:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for ryan: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for ryan: 
root@ubuntu:/home/ryan# sudo su
root@ubuntu:/home/ryan# apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package bcmwl-kernel-source is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@ubuntu:/home/ryan# echo brcmsmac >> /etc/modules
root@ubuntu:/home/ryan# exit

it still doesn't work

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of these two terminal commands: lspci -nn | grep 0280 and also: lsmod | grep -e wl -e brcmsmac

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Broadcom STA driver is incorrect for your device 14e4:4727. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo su
apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
echo brcmsmac >> /etc/modules
exit
```

Reboot and your wireless should be operating correctly.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work, i'll edit my original question to show what happened in terminal because i can't post it in a comment.

Comment: Let's also see: lsmod | grep brcmsmac and also: rfkill list all and also: iwconfig. It may be easier to paste the results here and give us the link in your reply. http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: these are the results from those commands,i put them on ubuntu pastebin like you suggested. Also, thank you for your help, it seems like ubuntu has a tough learning curve when you start out http://paste.ubuntu.com/5975098/

Comment: That looks very fine! Let's dig deeper: sudo iwlist wlan0 scan and also: nm-tool and also: dmesg | grep wlan0  Use paste.ubuntu.com again, please.

Comment: this is what i got this time http://paste.ubuntu.com/5976073/

Comment: i still haven't gotten it to work, can anyone "hear" me? lol

Comment: Sorry! Please detach the ethernet and see if you see networks: sudo iwlist wlan0 scan Is the hardware switch on or off? rfkill list all Are there any other clues in the logs? dmesg | grep -e wlan -e brcm  Please use paste.ubuntu.com again.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6012137/ right now it looks like the hardware switch is stuck on off, but when i click it the led stays the same color (orange), but under connections the message that says "wireless connections are disabled by hardware switch" goes on and off when i press it. So i'm not sure what's going on there, plus I could have sworn that the hardware switch was on (blue) before and wasn't being weird.

Comment: Very strange. In the paste, rfkill shows as not blocked; i.e. the switch is set to _enable_ wireless. Is it changed? rfkill list all Please reboot and let me see all of: dmesg in a paste. Something's crazy here.

Comment: this is what i got for dmesg http://paste.ubuntu.com/6016252/  also http://paste.ubuntu.com/6016263/  also, i noticed i had bluetooth turned off,and when i turned it on immediacy the additional drivers window popped up and said "no proprietary drivers are in use on this system", and listed broadcom sta wireless driver as one i could install, so tried activating the driver. but it just said Sorry, installation of this driver failed.

Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log         i feel like activating this driver might fix this, but i can't find the log file

Comment: You reinstalled 'Additional Drivers' which is bcmwl-kernel-source. In my answer, I requested that you remove it because it is wrong for your device. Please remove it again. Reboot. Give me a paste of dmesg and resist the urge to activate 'Additional Drivers' at all cost. It installs the WRONG driver for your device!

Comment: ok, i removed additional drivers and ran dmesg in terminal again http://paste.ubuntu.com/6020063/

Comment: I see this in your dmesg: "cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: XV" I am unaware of any country code 'XV.' What is your country code from here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Does your wireless scan? sudo iwlist wlan0 scan

Comment: i live in California, so i think the code should be .us. when i run sudo iwlist wlan0 scan i get "wlan0      No scan results"

Comment: Please try: sudo iw reg set US and then scan again. If it helps, we'll make US permanent.

Comment: i still get "no results found" after running sudo iw reg set US, even after rebooting.

Comment: Does  sudo iw reg set US a temporary thing, or was it permanent?

Comment: It is temporary. To make it permanent, do: gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local. Right above exit 0, add the line: iw reg set US. Proofread, save and close gedit. Reboot. Verify with: sudo iw reg get.

Comment: There is an updated brcmsmac in the package linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic. Please find it in the Software Center or Synaptic. I suggest you install it and reboot.

Comment: i did the first thing, but when i verify i get http://paste.ubuntu.com/6035653/ instead of US, I'm not sure if my country code is correct or not now.

Comment: when i tried to install the package (from here http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/canonical_kernel_team/precise/main/base/linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic) it said "dependency is not satisfiable". i only tried the 64 bit version though, because i have a 64 bit computer and 64 bit Ubuntu.

Comment: From your paste, it shows country 00, meaning default, one size fits all. You may have better performance with your actual country. Did you set it in /etc/rc.local?

Comment: Do you have a temporary wired ethernet connection so that you can do: sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic?

Comment: i did set my country to US, but it still says 00. i have been using a wired connection with my laptop to copy things from terminal to pasteubuntu. http://paste.ubuntu.com/6038476/

Comment: I would try: sudo apt-get update and if there are no errors or warnings, sudo apt-get install -- reinstall linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic

Comment: i installed the first set of updates, now i will and try the next step. the download worked, but got interrupted once, i think it was just my connection though.

Comment: when i tried the second step it couldn't locate the package to reinstall. http://paste.ubuntu.com/6049427/  do i enter "sudo apt-get install -- reinstall linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic" as one line into terminal?

Comment: Yes, please; one line.

Comment: when i ran it as one line it didn't work, this is what i got paste.ubuntu.com/6049427

Comment: It is not '--  reinstall' it is instead '--reinstall' with no space. Please try again.

Comment: i think the reinstall worked http://paste.ubuntu.com/6071860/

Comment: the wireless still isn't working though